# PICTURE statement using custom format

Tags: sas

I have a custom format:

```
proc format;
 value tmp 0='zero'
           1='one'
           2='two'
           3='three'
           4='four'
           5='five'
           6='six'
           7='seven'
           8='eight'
           9='nine'
run;
```

I want to use it in the picture statement so that for value `2.8` I would get `two point eight`. For now I get only `2 point 8`:

```
proc format;
    picture form 0-9="0 point 0"
        (decsep='point');
run;

data _null_;
    x=2.8;
    put x form.;
run;
```

How can I achieve getting `two point eigth`? Is using PICTURE statement a good choice?

Comment: What version of SAS do you have?

Comment: @Joe SAS 9.4 TS Level 1M0

Comment: It is not what you want, but WORDS and WORDF writes numbers as text, but the decimal as fractions

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure if you can do this with a picture format or not.  But, you can definitely do it with a function format in versions of SAS that support them.

Here we write a short function that creates the values you want as formatted values - using your previously defined format - and then use that as the argument to proc format.  I use a few extra lines of code to make it easier to read, but you could probably do this all in the return statement if you wanted to.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.functions.test;
   function wordnum(_number) $;
      length pre_dec post_dec $5;
      length _return_val $17;     
      pre_dec = put(floor(_number),tmp5.);  *the integer portion;
      post_dec = put(floor((_number-floor(_number))*10),tmp5.); *the decimal;
      _return_val = catx(' point ',pre_dec,post_dec);
      return (_return_val);
   endsub;

quit;

options cmplib=work.functions;

proc format;
    value form (default=17) 0-9.99= [wordnum()];  *use whatever range is appropriate;
quit;

data _null_;
  do x = 0.05 to 9.95 by 0.1;
    put x= form17.;
   end;
run;
```

Comment: I think to do this with just picture format you might have to do a separate line for each digit, so ten lines, and use prefix to get the integer portion.  `prefix="zero point "` and then append the [format].  Or build it in a data step by hand and write all possible values to proc format.

Comment: Also - you could of course simply use the function in the data step instead of the extra step of making a function, if that works for your use case.  The format of course is perfectly usable anywhere formats are allowed, including in the data step or procs.

Answer (score 0):

```
proc format;
 value $tmp '0'='zero'
           '1'='one'
           '2'='two'
           '3'='three'
           '4'='four'
           '5'='five'
           '6'='six'
           '7'='seven'
           '8'='eight'
           '9'='nine';
run;

data _null_;
    x=2.8;
    _x=cat(put(strip(scan(x,1,'.')),$tmp.),'point ',put(strip(scan(x,-1,'.')),$tmp.));
    put _all_;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question; while this works in the data step, it isn't very flexible in terms of using it more than one time and isn't usable in procs.  I have to assume the OP is asking for a format because a format is either more re-usable or is necessary for using in a proc.